# How to show values in textbox from database?

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0, textbox

Hi i have database like this

### Users Table

```
     user_id |   username  |  branch_id(foreignkey)|  Approved_id(foreignkey)
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1          jprescott         2                          1
    2          lpausch           1                          3
```

Branch Table

---

```
Branch_id    BranchName        
1                abc                    
2               asjdv                 
3               ydgfs
```

Approvetable

---

```
     ApproveId  ApprovedBy
          1         Anil
           2         ghouse
           3         raghu
```

now i have 3 textboxes,how do i these fields in the textboxes

```
          txtusername.text=username from table 1;
          txtapprovedname=approved by from table 2;
          txtbranchname=branchname from table 3;
```

when user 1 logins it should check the branch id and go to the branch table and disply the branch name,and check the approveid and go to the approvedtable and displya the approvedname in textboxes.....

now how to write a select statement for this can any one help me plz...........

Comment: You need to edit your question. the tables are uncleared and I only see 2 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select UsersTable.username, ApproveTable.ApprovedBy, Branchtable.BranchName
from UsersTable, Branchtable, Approvetable
where UsersTable.branch_id = BranchTable.branch_id
AND UsersTable.approved_id = ApproveTable.ApproveId
AND UsersTable.User_id = %CurrentUserID%
```

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348288/how-to-show-database-values-on-textboxes/9348299#9348299